# Where can I find systemjs.config in Ionic 2 Project?

Tags: angularjs, angular, typescript, ionic2

I create an pure Ionic 2 project with the command.

```
ionic start myIonic --v2
```

The pure project work great, but when I compared the project structure with  angularJS 2, I found the `"systemjs.config.js"` is missing.

My question is could "systemjs.config.js" file be replaceable?

If the answer is positive, what is the alternative file in Ionic2 based project ?

Answer (score 0):

i have created a angularjs 2 based poject using angular2-cli using below command.

> ng new PROJECT_NAME

when i create the project using angular2 cli, then also its not creating systemjs.config.js file.

[link for angular2 cli new app](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli) .

And Systemjs.config.js file is creating in angular2 project only if i create quick start application, that too we are only creating manually. as given in official quick start document.
[link for angular2 quick start app](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html).

So using this 2 examples we can believe that systemjs.config.js file can be replaceable.

Comment: Thanks for replying first, and one more question, so what is the alternative file relative to "systemjs.config.js" ?

Answer (score 0):

The angular-cli and ionic moved the build system from SystemJS to Webpack.

**For angular**

```
npm uninstall -g angular-cli
npm cache clean
npm install -g angular-cli@latest
```

Full angular-cli migrate docs: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/Upgrading-from-Beta.10-to-Beta.14