# Ionic 2 changed to webpack where should I add a map

Tags: angular, ionic2

I am trying to use a node package:
[angular2-social-login](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-social-login)

However they ask to add:

> dding angular2-social-login to your project
>   Add map for angular2-social-login in your systemjs.config

I tried to find systemjs.config but there isnt one since they changed to webpack:
[Where can I find systemjs.config in Ionic 2 Project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40214835/where-can-i-find-systemjs-config-in-ionic-2-project)

My question is, hmm where should I add:

`'angular2-social-login': 'node_modules/angular2-social-login/dist/bundles/angular2-social-login.min.js'`

Thanks in advance guys, this is really picking my brain :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you don't have to do this as long as Ionic does not use SystemJS.

Just

- install it (with npm)
- import the module using ES6' import in your .ts files

  import { XPTO } from 'angular2-social-plugin'
- and, if needed, import css files in theme/variable.scss

Answer (score 1):

Ionic doesn't use systemJS, so you don't have to do that step. SystemJS loads modules in the browser at runtime. Ionic will do this during the build step.

Simply install the package and then include it in the import section of your `app.module.ts` (as described in the readme).

```
import { Angular2SocialLoginModule } from "angular2-social-login";

@NgModule({
  imports: [ 
     ...Ionic modules...,
     Angular2SocialLoginModule
  ],
  ...
})

 Angular2SocialLoginModule.loadProvidersScripts(providers);
```

After importing the module you can use it anywhere in your project.